# Where is the ASP.NET Identity documentation?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have been going through [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/introduction-and-overview) and I've come across some some code in it that I would like to read about, but I am having a hard time finding the documentation for Identity.  I have already done more Googling than I usually have to do to find something, but I've had no luck.  I thought [Microsoft's ASP.NET Identity page](http://www.asp.net/identity) would probably be a good place to start, but all I have found there are articles and tutorials, and I would really like to find a manual.

Comment: well asp.net/identity is the perfect start i believe. your reference link contains *WingtipToys* web project with full explanation. What else you would like to read about for Asp.net Identity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the MSDN **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity Namespace** documentation:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity(v=vs.111).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)